# Shared preferences to String array

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, imageurl

I would like to know how I would be able to able achieve getting the strings from my shared preferences(I have already set up), then outputting it to a String array so that my Image Fetcher will be able to read it(It has to be an array for it to read).

In one activity I am setting the shared preferences:

```
        case R.id.FavouriteWallpaper:

        SharedPreferences prefs;
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("imgUrl", mImageUrl);
        editor.commit();

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

In another class I am getting the string from shared preferences:

```
            SharedPreferences prefs;
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        prefs.getString("imgUrl", null); //Output imgUrl to String Array somehow


 // I would like my image fetcher to read a string array that has been fetched from shared preferences. 

mImageFetcher.loadImage(Fragment3.imgUrl[position
                - mNumColumns], imageView);

        return imageView;
    }
```

Comment: u can take idea from my solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not really save an array to SharedPrerences, but you can store all your urls in a string like CSV (comma separated values) and store it in sharePreferences. You can write a manager that will have 2 methods. One to transform your array to CSV and store and the second get the CSV and transform it to an array.
The second method is to save the data like a JSONArray to do this you also need to write a manager that will have 2 methods also, one to transform your array to JSONArray and store it in Shared Preferences, and the second to transform the jsonArray into your array.

Comment: OK, thanks for the advice, do you have any examples that I could take a look at?

Comment: [Here is the LINK](https://github.com/croitor-ivan/sources/blob/master/SaveToSharedPrefs)

Answer (score 0):

you can get the strings using for loop

examole...

```
     SharedPreferences prefs;
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("imgUrl", mImageUrl);


for(int i=0; i<arraylist.size(); i++)
{
 editor.putString("imgUrl"+i, arraylist.get(i).toString());

}
 editor.commit();
```